# android: InstallAppProgress: Installation error code: -15

Tags: android

My app works fine when I run it via android studio in emulator/mobile But when I try to install app via apk (copying the apk to mobile then installing it) it shows error

App not installed

So, I tried to check the problem via

```
$adb logcat
```

Error log

```
12-13 11:58:23.599 20566 20792 E Parcel  : Reading a NULL string not supported here.
    12-13 11:58:23.602 20768 20781 D OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7fa272d400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f92e8cde0
    12-13 11:58:23.615 20566 20791 W Settings: Setting install_non_market_apps has moved from android.provider.Settings.Global to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
    12-13 11:58:23.833   447   447 W SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
    12-13 11:58:23.854   700 20795 D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]:  hostname=safebrowsing.google.com; servname=(null);   app_uid=0; ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0 from prox result 11
    12-13 11:58:23.979   700 20795 D libc-netbsd: res_queryN name = safebrowsing.google.com succeed
    12-13 11:58:23.979 20566 20791 D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]:  hostname=safebrowsing.google.com; servname=(null);   app_uid=10036; ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0 from prox result 0
    12-13 11:58:23.983 20566 20791 I Finsky  : [18995] com.google.android.finsky.foregroundcoordinator.ForegroundCoordinator.a(9): Task 7 requested foreground
    12-13 11:58:23.984 20566 20791 I Finsky  : [18995] com.google.android.finsky.foregroundcoordinator.ForegroundCoordinator.a(35): Not entering foreground
    12-13 11:58:24.025   700 20797 D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]:  hostname=safebrowsing.google.com; servname=(null);   app_uid=0; ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=2 from prox result 11
    12-13 11:58:24.026   700 20797 D libc-netbsd: res_queryN name = safebrowsing.google.com succeed
    12-13 11:58:24.026 20566 20613 D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]:  hostname=safebrowsing.google.com; servname=(null);   app_uid=10036; ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=2 from prox result 0
    12-13 11:58:24.092  7868  7868 E NetCtrlSig: tempServiceState is null1
    12-13 11:58:24.453 20566 20798 I Finsky  : [18999] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.co.b(6): Verification id=36 response=0
    12-13 11:58:24.467 20566 20566 I Finsky  : [1] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.de.c(102): Verifying id=36, result=1
    12-13 11:58:24.469 20566 20566 I Finsky  : [1] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.de.c(115): Verification complete: id=36, package_name=com.ethrmusic.ethrApp
    12-13 11:58:24.472 17711 18447 D DefContainer: Copying /storage/emulated/0/app-debug.apk to base.apk
    12-13 11:58:24.489  1459  1572 W PackageManager: installPackageLI
    12-13 11:58:24.494  1459  1572 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Explicit
    12-13 11:58:24.750  1459  1572 I art     : Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 54228(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 10(3MB) LOS objects, 25% free, 47MB/63MB, paused 2.730ms total 255.997ms
    12-13 11:58:24.750  1459  1572 V PackageManager: install fail
    12-13 11:58:24.751  1459  1572 D         : doWriteRawPartition::CriticalLogServiceManager = 0x7f85b87998
    12-13 11:58:24.752   707   707 D         : criticallog, do not add to dropbox type=40
    12-13 11:58:24.753  1459  1572 D         : doReadCriticalData::CriticalLogServiceManager = 0x7f85b87998
    12-13 11:58:24.753  1459  1572 V OppoManager: updateLogReference read now type=40 ref=40:APK安装失败:5
    12-13 11:58:24.754  1459  1572 D         : doWriteCriticalData::CriticalLogServiceManager = 0x7f85b87998
    12-13 11:58:24.757  1459  1572 V OppoManager: updateLogReference res=20
    12-13 11:58:24.757  1459  1572 D         : doReadCriticalData::CriticalLogServiceManager = 0x7f85b87998
    12-13 11:58:24.758  1459  1572 V OppoManager: updateLogReference read backup type=1064 ref=40:APK安装失败:13
    12-13 11:58:24.758  1459  1572 D         : doWriteCriticalData::CriticalLogServiceManager = 0x7f85b87998
    12-13 11:58:24.759  1459  1572 V OppoManager: updateLogReference res=21
    12-13 11:58:24.759  1459  1572 V PackageManager: record end
    12-13 11:58:24.780 20768 20768 D InstallAppProgress: Installation error code: -15
    12-13 11:58:25.090  7868  7868 E NetCtrlSig: tempServiceState is null1
```

What is the Installation error code: -15?

Comment: It's a debug or release apk? Also, do you have proguard activated?

Comment: Currently, this app is in a development phase. This apk is created when I run the app.
No, Proguard is not activated.

Comment: Just witnessed the same problem when distributing a new apk version over beta (crashlytics) app. also debug apk, no proguard activated

Comment: UPDATE: rebuilding the apk and distributing it again solved my issue. it seems like something was broking during the upload. maybe you wanna try rebuild the apk as well?

Comment: Thanks rebuilding the apk worked for me.

Android Studio >> Build >> BuildAPK(s)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create release APK, it should help.

-15 means this:

```
/**
     * Installation return code: this is passed in the {@link PackageInstaller#EXTRA_LEGACY_STATUS}
     * if the new package failed because it has specified that it is a test-only package and the
     * caller has not supplied the {@link #INSTALL_ALLOW_TEST} flag.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    @SystemApi
    public static final int INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY = -15;
```